# Angular2: get unparsed version of current route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Within my application I want to load context sensitive help texts, so texts based on the current location of the application.
However, when the visitor is on a location with an id parameter, no separate help text per id should be loaded, but only the general version. I recon the unparsed path is best suited for this purpose.

Some code as clearification:

Current route:
/page/1 resolves to the PageComponent:

```
{path: '/page/:pageid', component: PageComponent}
```

I want to show the help text for this PageComponent. So for retreiving the help text, I want to have the unparsed path (/page/:pageid) as variable.

I'm using RC4 at the moment, but all directions to the solution are welcome.

**Edit**: It seems that normally the code below should work

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.route.snapshot._routeConfig.path);
    });
}
```

However, actually the given Route is a child Route:

```
{
    path: 'app',
    component: Core,
    children: [
       {path: 'page/:pageid', component: PageComponent}
    ]
}
```

Resulting in "app" in the console.

**Edit 2**: close, but not quit yet...

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let state = this.router.routerState;
        console.log(state.firstChild(state.firstChild(state.root)).toString());
    });
}
```

Results in:

```
Route(url:'page/1', path:'page/:pageid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it in this way:

1. Import the routes
2. Subscribe to router.events to get url ([doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#events-anchor))
3. On url change, loop on the routes's path, see if the pattern match
   the url

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging in the core js files, I have come to the following solution:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const state = this.router.routerState;
        this.url = state.firstChild(state.firstChild(state.root)).snapshot._routeConfig.path;
    });
}
```

The digging was into @angular/router/src/router_state.js:

```
RouterState.prototype.toString = function () { return this.snapshot.toString(); };

...

ActivatedRouteSnapshot.prototype.toString = function () {
    var url = this.url.map(function (s) { return s.toString(); }).join('/');
    var matched = this._routeConfig ? this._routeConfig.path : '';
    return "Route(url:'" + url + "', path:'" + matched + "')";
};
```

This gave me enough information for the forementioned solution.